# Solspace Facebook Connect {fbc_publish_to_facebook} failing on comments but works on ratings

Tags: solspace, solspace-facebookconnect

As the title says, I've implemented Solspace Facebook Connect's {fbc_publish_to_facebook} but it's not working for comments. It does work fine on ratings.

Could this be because I'm submitting my comments via AJAX?

Any other reasons why the sharing to facebook would fail on comments?

Is there any way to debug it so I can see why it's failing?

I don't get any error or indication that it has failed. The comment simply doesn't get posted to facebook and I have no reason why.

The prepare page tags and all other necessities are there.

Comment: Would it be important to mention that we sent you a patch to resolve the issue with Rating comment publishing? Did you try publishing *without* using AJAX? Does it work then?

Comment: I didn't think the other issue with rating publishing had any relation, as that was an issue of the comment formatting field, not whether or not it published at all. I'll have to do some more testing without AJAX to see if it works that way.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm what version of ExpressionEngine and Facebook Connect you are using?

If it's v2.8 (latest) there are issues with a new, more verbose security model. I have submitted a patch to SolSpace for my issue where the facebook registration plugin was causing an EE Form out of date error.

If not, please ignore me!

Comment: Thanks but I'm still on EE 2.7